# Google Guice: Provider with parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a constructor that depends on classes A and B. I defined it like this:

```
@Inject TestClass(A a, B b)
```

Is there a way in Guice to have one of the constructor parameters injected manually?

Problem is, the object of class `A` cannot be built as it depends on the user input. I was just wondering if Guice supports a provider that accepts an argument. For example, currently an object can be created by `provider.get()`, does Guice has one that support `provider.get(a)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you need is [Assisted Inject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).